# having problems with keyListener

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, thread-sleep, focusable

i am trying to make a simple reaction test in java.
when the screen turns green i press space witch is supposed to change te boolean "clicked into false and stop the loop that measures time. 
in reality the key listner does nothing. 
am i adding the keay listener to the right compnent( jpanel panel)?
is there any other problems?

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.RenderingHints.Key;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;        
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class mainCheck {
    // //////////////////////////////////////
    public static void timeKeeper() {
         boolean clicked=false;
        long time = 10000;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        while (time > 0 && !clicked) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            time--;
        }
        panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        long time2= 10000-time;
        JLabel x = new JLabel("" +time2+"");
        panel.add(x);    
    }

    // //////////////////////////////////////
    static boolean clicked;
    JFrame frame;
    static JPanel panel;

    public mainCheck() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();
        clicked = false;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        frame.addKeyListener(handler);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    // //////////////////////////////////////

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mainCheck f = new mainCheck();
        panel.getActionMap();           
        f.timeKeeper();
    }

    // //////////////////////////////////////
    public class Handler implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                clicked = false;
                System.out.println("space pressed");
            }    
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- do not use `Thread.sleep(5000);` block [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and during sleep you can lost all events to the already visible Swing GUI
- use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead
- `Thread.sleep(1);`  could be proper delay for space enviroment, non_human, very short period attacking latency in Native OS (8-14miliseconds, depends of Native OS)
- `JLabel x = new JLabel("" +time2+"");` and `panel.add(x);` in AWT/Swing isn't any notifiers that some, any, part of `JComponents` are removed or added, have to notify used `LayoutManager` (`JPanel` has `FlowLayou`t in API) by using methods `revalidate` and `repaint`, e.g.

.

```
JLabel x = new JLabel("" +time2+"");
panel.add(x);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

- Swing GUI should be created on [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
- don't to use [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead, otherwise you (are focus hunter) would need to set `panel.seFocusable(true);`

Answer (score 0):

- The problem is that you "**e.getKeyCode()**" always is "**0**" so
  change for "**e.getKeyChar()**" and "**(char)32**"
- the other problem is in that you put **clicked = false** and must be
  "**true**"
- And the last problem you have is in "**timeKeeper()**" you have to erase "**boolean**" because it is already declarated

  ```
  Bad
  public static void timeKeeper() {
  boolean clicked=false
  ....}

  Good
  public static void timeKeeper() {
  clicked=false
  ....}
  ```

This is the correct code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;        
import javax.swing.*;

public class mainCheck {
// //////////////////////////////////////
public static void timeKeeper() {
    clicked=false;
    long time = 10000;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    while (time > 0 && !clicked) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        time--;
    }
    panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
    long time2= 10000-time;
    JLabel x = new JLabel("" +time2+"");
    panel.add(x);    
}

// //////////////////////////////////////
static boolean clicked;
JFrame frame;
static JPanel panel;
Handler handler = new Handler();

public mainCheck() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    panel = new JPanel();
    clicked = false;

    frame.addKeyListener(handler);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
// //////////////////////////////////////

public static void main(String[] args) {
    mainCheck f = new mainCheck();
    panel.getActionMap();           
    f.timeKeeper();
}

// //////////////////////////////////////
public class Handler implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == (char)32) {
            clicked = true;
            System.out.println("space pressed");
        }    
    }  
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a really bad idea to use Thread.sleep() to decrement the time value.
Use a `Timer` object instead:

```
public void myTimer(){
    Timer myTimer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //Stuff to do
        }
    });
}
```

Where `delay` is the amount of time you delay the timer. You start the timer with myTimer.start();

Comment: -1 The suggestion to use a Timer was given 30 minutes earlier. No need to clutter the forum with duplicate suggestions.